# Is it possible to add an already existing CRD into a custom Kubernetes operator using Go?

Tags: wordpress, go, kubernetes, client-go, kubernetes-operator

I'm currently working on my own custom operator that deploys a fully functional Wordpress. I'm required to implement SSL. Now this is where I'm stuck, I'm not really sure how to implement this using Go.

Is there a way of adding already existing CRDs, for example cert-manage, into my operator and then create a Kubernetes resource type out of these, using my custom Operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every Go controller also has clients generated. See e.g. [client-go cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/tree/master/pkg/client).

If you import the client-go for cert-manager, you can use it to e.g. `create` resources or `watch` for changes.